# Взаимодействие select и input

Tags: html, css, jquery

У меня есть следующий select:

```
<div>
                                        <select>
                                            <option value="">Пункт 1</option>
                                            <option value="">Пункт 2</option>
                                            <option value="">Другое</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
```

Нужно реализовать следующую функцию:
Т.е. при выборе пункта "другое", текст внутри select должен пропасть и должна появиться возможность ввода информации с клавиатуры. Но! При этом возможность выбора других пунктов у select должна остаться. 
Такой механизм реально реализовать? И если да, то с чего начать?...

Comment: Да запросто, вы просто добавляете ниже `input` который скрыт, при событии `onchange` проверяете текущее значение селекта и если = другое, тогда показываете этот инпут и делаете на него фокус к примеру, иначе скрыть инпут )

Comment: @RifmaMan а как при этом оставить возможность выбора opion в select?

Comment: Select и input - два разных html element'a с разными поведениями. Можно сделать кастомный input который будет работать по принципу select но вы потеряете стандартное поведение элементов

Comment: ```Но! При этом возможность выбора других пунктов у select должна остаться```
Вы пытаетесь скрестить осла и лошадь. Это два совершенно разных элемента с разными поведениями

Comment: @polRk т.е. такой подход реализуем только если создавать кастомный input с поведением как у select?

Comment: @ВикторТюрин Да, обычно используются web компоненты  (react, vue, angular, stencil)

Comment: @polRk понял. А есть примеры реализации?

Comment: @ВикторТюрин вот https://material-ui.com/ru/components/autocomplete/, выбирайте

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100269/discussion-between-polrk-and--).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так вам нужно было?

```js
$(document).on('change', 'select', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 3) {
    $('input[name="other"]').show().focus();
  } else {
    $('input[name="other"]').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select>
    <option value="1">Пункт 1</option>
    <option value="2">Пункт 2</option>
    <option value="3">Другое</option>
  </select>
  <input name="other" value="" style="display: none;" />
</div>
```

Comment: не, не так я имел в виду. Т.е. внутри select-a должна появляться возможность написания текста

Comment: логически так никто не делает, в селекте четко должно быть значение 1, 2, 3 и свое, причем при клике на свое вводится название уже в другой элемент (т.к. сам селект не может принимать ввод от пользователя), конечно можно было бы и поколдовать, чтобы сэмитировать ваше решение, но это будет ужасно и так делать не стоит